# Is it acceptable for a prolog procedure to work only one way?

Tags: prolog, logic

I have a prolog program:

```
link(liverpool,preston).
link(liverpool,manchester).
link(preston,lancaster).
link(preston,manchester).
link(lancaster,carlisle).
link(lancaster,leeds).
link(carlisle,leeds).
link(manchester,leeds).

%checks to see if X is in the supplied list
inlist( X, [X|_]).
inlist( X, [_|Ys]) :- inlist( X, Ys).


merge([],L,L).

merge([H|T],BList,CList):-
inlist(H,BList),
merge(T,BList,CList).

merge([H|T],BList,[H|CList]):-
merge(T,BList,CList),
not(inlist(H,BList)).
```

Merge works if I call it like this:

`merge([a,b,c],[d,e,f],Result). --> [a,b,c,d,e,f]`

or more importantly, what it was designed to solve:

`merge([a,b,c],[a,d,e,f],Result). --> [a,b,c,d,e,f]`

but if I call merge like this:

`merge(X,[d,e,f],[a,b,c,d,e,f]).`

There is a stack overflow.  Is this generally acceptable behavior for a function that is designed to work one way?  Or is there some convention that functions should work in both ways?

Edit:  merge works if you call it like this:

`merge([a,b,c],X,[a,b,c,d,e,f]). --> [d,e,f]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should not call these "functions". "Predicates" is the correct term.

It's generally desirable for Prolog predicates to work "both ways". But it's not always possible or worth the effort in a particular situation.

To inform about ways a predicate is intended to be used mode-declarations can be used. These declarations conventions are different from system to system. These declarations are mostly serve as a documentation for programmers and rarely used by compilers, but can be used by testing frameworks and other helper tools.

Examples of conventions for mode declarations:

- SWI-Prolog: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=modes
- ECLiPSe CLP: http://eclipseclp.org/doc/applications/tutorial003.html#toc10 (scroll to 2.7.3  Mode declaration)

Also there is a convention (described in  "The Craft of Prolog", for example) that input parameters of a predicate come first, output parameters come last.

Comment: @mbratch - if you have specified (using Sergey's modes) that a predicate is not 2 way, then surely (like other languages ?) the behaviour of the 'other' way is 'undefined', in which case it could fail, do a stack overflow, make a cup of fine darjeeling tea, or anything it wants? Should code be explicitly written, in every case, to trap the 'other' way, and return fail ? Is this 'fail' behaviour you describe a standard or a convention, or a nice-to-have?

Comment: @mbratch: In any situation, a "stack overflow", that is, a resource error, or more generally non-termination, or an instantiation error is preferable to an incorrect or incomplete answer.

Comment: @false & magus - After I wrote my comment I did reconsider and I agree.

Comment: I understand, so on detection of unexpected variable assignment using eg. var/1 or nonvar/1, instantiation_error/1 should be called (as the final line of the predicate), which raises an exception to the caller.

Comment: I hunted down an example from http_path.pl in the source code:path_list(Var) -->
 { var(Var), !,
   instantiation_error(Var)
 }.

Comment: It would also be interesting to know if there is a standardised grammatical term for 'both ways' eg. 'reversible', or 'symmetrical', or something..

Comment: @magus, in Prolog terms I think it would be called "relational" since it could be two ways, three ways, etc, depending upon how many variables there are. :)

Comment: @false The reason I didn't like the stack overflow originally is that I'm used to the imperative programming world where it's bad practice to write a function which "crashes" (causes a segfault, for example), even if incorrect input is given. It's better to either succeed, return a "legitimate" error, or raise an exception that can be trapped by the caller. Perhaps this is a good subject for a separate SO/Prolog question. :)